# How to save the password for a SQL Azure Database in Application Settings in Azure?

Tags: azure, web-applications

I am using Linux Web Apps for Azure together with a SQL Azure Database.

I can save my SQL Azure Database password (for argument's sake, let us say it is `pass123`) in `META-INF/context.xml` and this works successfully

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
       factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
       driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" initialSize="30"
       maxActive="100" validationQuery="SELECT 1"
       validationQueryTimeout="1000"
       testOnBorrow="true"
       url="jdbc:sqlserver://exampleserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=exampledb;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=westeurope1-a.control.database.windows.net;
       loginTimeout=10;user=myuser;
       password=pass123"
            />
</Context>
```

I however would like the password to be encrypted and not stored in plaintext in the context.xml file. So I did the following - based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-java#data-sources:

I added two Web App/Configuration/Application Settings
`CATALINA_OPTS` and `THEDBPASSWORD`

I set `CATALINA_OPTS` to be `"$CATALINA_OPTS -Ddbpassword={THEDBPASSWORD}"`

I set `THEDBPASSWORD` to be the password of the user

[image: Picture from Azure Portal of Application Settings]

I then changed my `context.xml` to be `password={dbpassword}` instead of  `password=pass123`

I then however get the following error in the log (and the application fails to start)

```
Error: Could not find or load main class "$CATALINA_OPTS -Ddbpassword=pass123" -Ddbpassword=pass123
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following:

1. I had forgotten the $ in context.xml

So `context.xml` needed to be `password=${dbpassword}`

2. I also changed the `CATALINA_OPTS` to be `-Ddbpassword=pass123`
3. I dispensed with the `THEDBPASSWORD` variable

I am sure this is not the only way or the best way of doing this, but at least it works.
I was partly inspired by [Tomcat 8 - context.xml use Environment Variable in Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761831/tomcat-8-context-xml-use-environment-variable-in-datasource)