# Modifying a JNDI connection pool programmaticaly

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using Apache Tomcat JDBC connection pool library in my project and configured the context.xml file accordingly. My application instance needs to run at multiple locations, but load on the application will be different, so I want to modify the maxActive size and some other property based on the customer size at particular instance at runtime.

```
  <Context path="/abc"
             docBase="abc"
             debug="5"
             reloadable="false"
             crossContext="true">
       <Resource name="jdbc/abc"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          driverClassName="xxxxx"
          url="xxxxxxx"
          username="xxxxx" password="xxxxxx"
          maxActive="20"
          initialSize="0"
          ...
          />
     </Context>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Tomcat JDBC? Without using a `factory` attribute, Tomcat's default is to use a repackaged version of DBCP2.

Comment: thanks. factory missed while typing.

Comment: "multiple locations" -- Are you saying that the clients are on many machines but MySQL is on a single server?  How many?

Comment: @RickJames no Mysql also on same server. every application instance has its own DB.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using standard JMX for this purpose.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JMX), Tomcat can expose the connection pool as a [MBean object](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/jmx/ConnectionPoolMBean.java) you can interact with using tools like JConsole, for instance.

The [the MBean implementation](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/jmx/ConnectionPool.java) basically delegates to the actual [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.java)  the different operations that can be performed through the MBean interface and, AFAIK, `ConnectionPool` dynamically [allocates connections](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/d312165d13445972b276ec5d696f249cbc1b2f58/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.java#L663-L752) based on current configuration.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BASED ON CONFIGURATION AND NOT RUNTIME BEHAVIOR**

Please, consider review [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761831/tomcat-8-context-xml-use-environment-variable-in-datasource) and the [self provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492702/13942448), I think it could be helpful.

Tomcat substitutes system provided environment variables in its [configuration files](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/index.html):

> Tomcat configuration files are formatted as schemaless XML; elements and
> attributes are case-sensitive. Apache Ant-style variable substitution is
> supported; a system property with the name `propname` may be used in a
> configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All system properties are
> available including those set using the `-D` syntax, those automatically
> made available by the JVM and those configured in the
> `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties` file.

As indicated, the best way you could include the properties you need to dynamically being substituted by Tomcat is passing them as system properties using the `-D` option and probably in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.

As indicated in the afore mentioned question, and advised as well in `catalina.sh`:

```
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#
#   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
#   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.
#
```

define them, for example, in a `setenv.sh` file located in the `$CATALINA_BASE/bin` directory.

For example:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

export MAX_ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS=20

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DmaxActiveConnections=$MAX_ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS"
```

And use these properties in your XML configuration files:

```xml
<Context path="/abc"
         docBase="abc"
         debug="5"
         reloadable="false"
         crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/abc"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="xxxxx"
              url="xxxxxxx"
              username="xxxxx" password="xxxxxx"
              maxActive="${maxActiveConnections}"
              initialSize="0"
              ...
    />
</Context>
```

Comment: this does not sound like programmatic modification, which was asked by the OP

Comment: Thank you very much for point that out @eis. Sorry, I missed that part of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much again @eis. I updated the answer with a runtime based solution. Sorry for missing the runtime requirement the first time.

Comment: I support the JMX variant. No problem to get the MBean from the registry for programmatic modification. On the other hand, i would let the connection pool implementation handle the number of connections.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about a datasource created through JNDI: if you know its class (`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` in your case), you can cast to that class and use the available setters to configure it:

```java
    private void customizeDataSource(final DataSource ds) {
        if (ds instanceof PoolConfiguration) {
            final PoolConfiguration poolConfig = (PoolConfiguration) ds;
            poolConfig.setMaxActive(10);
        }
    }
```

(see the definition of [`PoolConfiguration`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html)). Implementations of `javax.sql.DataSource` also implement a very useful interface [`Wrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Wrapper.html), which may come handy if your code wraps the Tomcat JDBC datasource in something else:

```java
    private void customizeDataSource(final DataSource ds) throws SQLException {
        if (ds.isWrapperFor(PoolConfiguration.class)) {
            final PoolConfiguration poolConfig = ds.unwrap(PoolConfiguration.class);
            poolConfig.setMaxActive(10);
        }
    }
```

There are however some problems that can arise from the programmatic approach above:

- if you bundle `tomcat-jdbc.jar` with your application, only JNDI resources configured in your `context.xml` will be recognized by your code. Those in [GlobalNamingResources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/globalresources.html) will use the copy of `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` bundled with Tomcat and will not match the `instanceof` condition.
- if, on the other hand, you don't include `tomcat-jdbc.jar` into your WAR file, you must make sure that the parameters you set are supported by all versions of Tomcat on which your application will run.

Comment: Global Naming Resources could be accessed over Java Reflection. There are only few different data source implementations. One can iterate over multiple possible method names until it works...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL connects rapidly, thereby making connection pooling of limited use.

Usually, if there is a performance problem it is better handled by other techniques -- composite indexes, reformulating queries, working around optimization limitations of MySQL, etc.

Would you care to back up a step and let's analyze the bottlenecks?